# Got a job offer sent a counter proposal, got no response

Tags: salary, job-offer

I was interviewed for a software development job. A position which calls for expert level skill.

the hiring process was long and difficult , the final technical interview lasted more than a 4 hours.
after  this long interview, I was asked to wait for a few minutes  and meet the CTO,  he surprised me with the salary expectation question. After the long day I was tired & hungry so I asked what was the budget for this position. The answer he gave me was such a low ball I should have realized immediately this is a negotiation trick, But as I said I was out of focus and I blurred a number lower than I should have.

On my way home they emailed me with request for references,  once they spoke with them. they sent me an offer a few thousands / year less than what I asked.

Afer pondering the issue I emailed back , thanked them for their offer and asked politely for the original target (which is in line with what they pay in this company from what I know). I made no ultimatum just stated the gap is small and it would be nice if they can up their offer a bit.

that was  yesterday morning.  I got no response from them. I am at a complete loss of what to do now.  Given their quick response time since I began this process (hours) waiting so long is strange.

I would like to work there,  but I think that calling them asking for a response at this point, might not work to my advantage.

what are your thoughts ?

Comment: It is also a negotiation tactic, the ball is in their court, just wait and see what they say, don't ask again...

Comment: @Blue2Red: How did the story end? Did they reply back to you?

Comment: Curious to know what happened, did they respond you?

Comment: @fingerscrossedcareer FYI, you can click on someone's name to see their profile. If you do with the OP, you'll find they haven't logged in for over three years; we will likely never know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might have put yourself at a disadvantage by saying "it would be nice if you upped your offer". I can't be sure, because I don't know the exact contents of what your wrote, but the company might be waiting on something more definitive and actionable from you. It sounds to me like you didn't clearly reject the offer, so there might be some confusion about whether you're still thinking about it. The other possibility is that someone is working to get the higher rate approved and it takes some time because of internal pressures that you aren't aware of.

I would write a quick note to just touch base and let them know that you're still very interested in the position and that you're available if they need any more information from you. I wouldn't ask for a response unless you have a pressing deadline. Often just a follow-up to let them know that you're still interested can get things rolling again.

Comment: I re-read my response, it is not apologetic and has a clear actionable item (along the line of up you offer and lets move on) .   I like  your idea of expressing interest in the position without referring  explicitly to the offer, thanks.

Comment: @Blue2Red  Thanks for clearing that up. Thinking about it a bit more, you might want to write a typical "thanks for the interview " type follow up even though they already extended an offer. Enjoyed meeting you,  impressed with the company, etc. If you had interviewed with a more informal company, the formality of the thank you might come off a little weird, but it sounds like the interview process was quite extensive and formal.

Answer (score 16):

> that was yesterday morning. I got no response from them.

Woah. Chill out. You asked them a question which likely requires both:

- Talking to HR
- Talking to the manager's manager

This will not be immediate and might take a few days (or more). HR has a lot more concerns than just, "will Blue2Red take this job?" Especially if your counter was outside the money that the hiring manager had to "easily" budget

Keep in mind that while this is a huge priority and matter of urgency for you, it's not the most important thing that the hiring manager and HR will deal with today and yesterday. For all you know they had dozens of critical emails to deal with.

There are just plenty of more important things to most managers than some employee they are trying to hire... who might not even accept the offer.

If you don't hear back by maybe next Wednesday, send a followup that says "Hey, I haven't heard anything - let me know if you need anything else from me!"

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question how did you respond to the low ball offer, that changes the dynamics. If you haven't agreed with the low ball, it's totally ok to ask for more. As long as your request was reasonable, they shouldn't change their mind regarding hiring you. However, if you have agreed then changing your mind doesn't help you really.

In general, these questions are very standard (maybe except from junior positions at large corporations) and you should prepare for them.

Not getting a reply for a day is totally fine. Many people receive well over a hundred emails a day and it might take them a while to get back to you. Also, some people can't reply to this immediately (depending on who's the decision maker).

Anyway, you should wait at least for 2 weeks before pinging them again.

Comment: I responded to the low ball with the actual salary I know they pay in this place. as a result I got less than that. I am not impatient for now reason, up until now they kept  pushing  moving  to the next level whenever it was possible, So radio silence for that long is atypical of what I have seen so far.