# How can a candidate politely ask for an update on an unreturned callback?

Tags: interviewing, email

The subject might be all you need to understand the essence of the question, but for some context of my personal situation please read on:

I asked in an interview:

‘What would be your main concern regarding employing me?’

His reply was that one skill of mine wasn't as good as another. The implication being that he was hoping for both skills to be good.

He said he’d give me a chance to prove I had the skill in question by sending through something for me to do.

Great!  I can work this thing out, let’s do it!

I still haven't received it.

I figure he’s either: swamped at work and busy, made a decision other than me, decided that the test was redundant/unhelpful after all.

**Should I contact him?**
**How to phrase it so that I come off in no way ‘less employable’?**

Any advice appreciated

Comment: _he has failed to follow through on something._ Why would you think he has any obligation to follow through? He already told you your skills weren't as great as he was hoping for.

Comment: He said my PM skills "*perhaps* weren't as great as he was hoping for" ... Which is a conditional statement - it was also made as a relative comparison to my technical skills. It wasn't absolute as you've interpreted it. Furthermore, if someone says they will do something, I believe they have at least 'some' obligation to honour it, you might think at least contact when situations change? Why should interviews change this?

Comment: I looked at a few of the 'follow up after interview' questions - it does indeed have a lot of cross over. But my question perhaps is a bit more specific? Perhaps are you suggesting I shouldn't see it as any different?

Comment: Did it ever occur to you that the word "perhaps" was used to politely tell you the "No hire" decision? If he were so impressed with your skills, why would he say "perhaps weren't as great as he was hoping for"?

Comment: Yes, it is possible and I did consider it, my question at one point infers as much. But I can't assume. I was the first interviewed, maybe the other 3 were even worse ...  And again, it was a *relative* statement, *compared* with my technical skills.

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate. In particular, the [answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/6021/1193) would be useful to you, in my opinion. And I really like the last sentence: _Any time you spend waiting and hoping is potentially wasted time._ which is exactly what I was going to say. You already sent him two e-mails after the interview. In the second e-mail, you did mention the project. This should be enough. Good luck on the next interview! (You never know if the next one is much better than this one).

Comment: You would have to elaborate how your question is non-trivially different from the other ones. My first impression of the question from the description was, "No communication from hiring manager after the interview. Should I follow up, and if so, how?"

Comment: See [this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/43905/2322) for a whole variety of reasons this is way more important to you than it is to the manager who interviewed you. As I said there, "chill out." You've already sent two followup emails in three days after the interview.

Comment: Still don't understand your reasons for closing it scaahu. Potentially it's saying less about my question than something else. Perhaps I'll give less context next time, see if that works out.

Comment: Hi Lamar, a question being closed as a "duplicate" just means that all the answers there are also applicable here. It's not a bad thing at all. If your question is significantly different than the other, feel free to [edit] your question to be clear what the difference is or post on [meta](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/) to request community involvement. But you don't need to edit your question to be exactly the same. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, duplicates that are different enough in how they're asked can increase the odds that somebody searching for the answer to this question will find it -- they'll land here and follow the link or they'll land on the original, depending on what they searched for.  There's nothing wrong with having a question marked as a duplicate -- and, with luck, the fact that there are already answers gets *you* an answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hi, I'm touching base because I haven't received anything from you regarding what we discussed last week. The last message I received from you was on X; if I'm missing later messages please let me know. Thank you again for your time."

In other words, do not display entitlement or accuse him of "failing to do something." You're not going to do yourself any favors by getting into a proverbial pissing match. This potential employer does not owe you any kind of courtesy, and any given is freely given out of the goodness of his heart.

Answer (score 2):

**Call him**

If I were you, I'd try to call him via whatever professional phone number he provided, to ask if he's already sent something which somehow landed in e-mail limbo.

**Skype**

You also mentioned you talked with him on Skype, which usually indicated if a person is online or not. So try calling him on there. If he doesn't pick up, you can send a instant message explaining your situation.

**Approach**

Since you were also curious on how to phrase your questions. Just make sure to stay polite and honest. You were expecting a try-out project before the decision day. But you didn't get that yet. So just stay on point with what you want. *Which is the project ofcourse.*

Tip: It's probably also better to not say or imply he has 'failed' to do something. Even if he did, accidents happen and if he's still interested in you, you've got nothing to worry about.

Comment: Calling - perhaps I've read too much about interviewing lately but it's not recommended in general, it affords the receiver much less ability to manage their time. I wouldn't want to be the person who introduces any more of that. Skype, similar issues, but with the whole 'sorry, can you say that again?' and talking over each other because of the terrible latency. In person also out of the question as we're in different countries now.   But thanks yes for the general advice, it makes sense